# C programming - do while loop help (code almost done)

Tags: c

I have created a code that writes out the sum of all even numbers.
But every time it loops the sum of the last run is saved and added in the sum of the new run. how do i make it have a new loop?

sorry for my bad english, and thx in advance

```
 int main()
    {


    int number = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Welcome to\"Sum Evens\"!");

    do
    {
        printf("\ninput a number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &number);
        if (number == 0)
        {
            printf("Goodbye, have a nice day!\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("\nSum:");

        if (number % 2 != 0)
        {
            number -= 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i += 2)
        {

            printf(" %d ", i);
            if (i != number)
            {
                printf("+");
            }
            sum += i;

        }
        printf("= %d\n", sum);

    } while (number != 0);

    system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You need to put the sum=0 into the loop, before summing it

Comment: Try moving the definition of the variable `sum` into the loop.

Comment: Thx guys. you go blind working on your own code cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch these sort of problems melt away if you declare your variables as close to their first use as possible.

In your case, move `int sum = 0;` to just before the `for` loop.

Comment: Excellent advice.